# $.ajax JSON retrieval fails - JSP

Tags: java, json, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to receive JSON Array from Servlet and add data to a table.
But JSON or text don't come to jsp. I've try many things. Here is my JSP

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search a User</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#search1').click(function ()
            {
                var searchdata = $("#searchword").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "Search", //this is my servlet
                    data: {searchword :searchdata },
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="searchword">Search a User</label>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <input id="searchword" type="text" placeholder="Add User's name" class="form-control input-md" required="">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <button id="search1" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I just try to make sure the success function is working. But alert won't work. I added Alerts without string we retrieve from the Servlet for demo propose. But they also didn't work.  I'm pretty sure my fault is on the JSP side because I can see the JSON Array and Servlet retrieving the **search word** in the log4j logs. But for Make sure that I'll add the servlet also here.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import hsenid.DBConnector;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Search extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Search.class);


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        resp.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        String username = req.getParameter("searchword");
        DBConnector dbpool = (DBConnector) getServletContext().getAttribute("DBConnection");
        JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
        logger.info(username);
        try {
            Connection myConn = dbpool.getConn();
            String likeQuery = "Select * from userdetails WHERE username LIKE ?";
            preparedStatement = myConn.prepareStatement(likeQuery);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, "%" + username + "%");
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
                jsonObject.addProperty("firstName", resultSet.getString("fname"));
                jsonObject.addProperty("lastName", resultSet.getString("lname"));
                jsonObject.addProperty("dob", resultSet.getString("dob"));
                jsonObject.addProperty("country", resultSet.getString("country"));
                jsonObject.addProperty("email", resultSet.getString("email"));
                jsonObject.addProperty("mobile", resultSet.getString("mnumber"));
                jsonObject.addProperty("username", resultSet.getString("username"));

                jsonArray.add(jsonObject);

            }
            logger.info("JSON ARRAY Created");

            logger.info(jsonArray.toString());
            resp.getWriter().write(jsonArray.toString());
            out.println(jsonArray);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: See the browser console error and tell us. To open console in firefox `CTRL+SHIFT+J`

Comment: Thanks Ataur. At that moment I had no idea how to reply your question and then I got to know about firebug. Question solved :)

Comment: Cheers. @Menuka ishan :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the result JSON array twice, so the content is not a valid JSON response, and JQuery will not be able to parse it:

```
resp.getWriter().write(jsonArray.toString());
out.println(jsonArray);   // out is resp.getWriter()
```

So simply remove the second line.

To better diagnose such errors you should also add an `error` callback to your `$.ajax` call and look at the developer console if it shows any errors.